# Magento 2 Add javascript to single page

Tags: magento2, layout, javascript, magento-2.1

I'm trying to get some JavaScript in the head on a single CMS page in Magento 2 and cannot figure it out.  I understand how to extend layouts to include this, but I don't want the script on all pages that use a layout.  Unfortunately this script does have to be loaded before the page body loads for it to work.

In Magento 1, I simply added this to the Layout Update XML:

```
<reference name="head">
    <block type="core/text" name="blockname">
        <action method="setText">
            <text>
                <![CDATA[<script type="text/javascript">
```

However, that doesn't work in Magento 2.

Is there any way to do this?  It seems so simple, yet I've hit a wall trying to figure it out.

By the way, been a long-time lurker, and you guys are great.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try admin side

Answer (score 1):

If you use a cms site, you can create a **cmsyourname.phtml**.
Now you can insert your jquery in the top of the file.

In your cms page in the backend, you have to add this:

{{block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="cmsyourname" template="Magento_Cms::html/**cmsyourname.phtml**"}}

Comment: Hi Irv,
Thanks, I'll give that a try.
Where would the phtml file get placed in the directory structure?  Would it be under Magento_Cms/templates in our theme?

Comment: Hiho, yea that's it!

Comment: Example: 

app/design/frontend/Theme/Themename/Magento_Cms/templates/html/**YOUREFILEHERE**

Comment: @CorLiving_Web did that help you?

Comment: Hi Irv,
I don't think that worked.  It's not that I'm trying to load jquery, I'm trying to add some custom functions.
Thanks for your help, but I think I'll just have them load for every CMS page and not worry about having them only on 1 page.

Answer (score 1):

I went about doing this a different way. Maybe it's not possible the way I wanted it done.

I actually ended up scripting a CURL to pull the CMS page and just insert the javascript that I wanted in between comment placeholders. I realize this is terribly inefficient, but I could not figure out how else to just get a small JS function added to a single CMS page in Magento.

If anybody else knows how to accomplish this, I welcome a solution